# Fourier transform of a 3D list {x,y,value}

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a list of x and y coordinates and values corresponding to it. (Note: I don't have a function).

```
x={-0.245950028300285339, -2.980232238769531250*10^-8, 0.245949983596801758, -0.122975006699562073, 0.122974991798400879, -0.122975021600723267, 0.122974991798400879, -0.245950028300285339, -2.980232238769531250*10^-8, 0.245949983596801758};
y={-0.07100000977516174316, -0.07100000977516174316, -0.07100000977516174316, 0.1419989466667175293, 0.1419989466667175293, -0.141998931765556335, -0.141998931765556335, 0.07100000977516174316,0.07100000977516174316, 0.07100000977516174316};
value={0.2306764274835586548, 0.4253199100494384766, 0.1735137999057769775, -0.408258259296417236, -0.262855947017669678, 0.262874633073806763, -0.4082381129264831543, 0.1735334247350692749, -0.425331473350524902, 0.230725541710853577};
```

So, the data and density plot I have is:

```
data = Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]], value[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[x]}];
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All];
```

Now, I need a fourier/InverseFourier similar plot, which way should I procced with? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you

Comment: Can you share the method?